# Save credit card to recurly payment gateway

Tags: recurly

Is the Recurly payment gateway provides to save the customer's credit card information using API and customers can select one of the card on the payment page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Recurly stores the customer's credit card data within the customer's account. For future purchases, all you need to do is reference the customer's account code and the stored billing information will be used.